# The limitation $\lim\limits_{t\to \infty}(1+t)^a\int_0^{t}(1+t-\tau)^{-b}(1+\tau)^{-2a}d\tau $?

Tags: calculus, integration

I want to prove the existence of the limitation

$$\lim\limits_{t\to \infty}(1+t)^a\int_0^{t}(1+t-\tau)^{-b}(1+\tau)^{-2a}d\tau $$

for some positive parameters $a,b$ to be determined. I trie to consider the order of the power functions directly, i.e.

$$b+2a-1\ge a$$

This seems to be somewhat rigorous and doesn't work on the critical point, such as $a=0,b=1$. How can I prove the convergence for different $a,b$ values?

Comment: The formula in title and body are not the same (first exponent in the integrand). Please fix it.

Comment: It is not clear as to what you are asking. If the question is about existence of the integral why do have $(1+t)^{a}$? Are you talking about some limiting value of the expression?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Thank you. I have fixed my question.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Yes, I want to ask the existence of the limitation of the integral actually. But I didn’t express it clearly. Sorry.